# Getting Items out of a Json Array

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I wanted to get Strings/ints of several Items out of a JSON Array, but I don't really know how I can achieve that

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(jsonRequest("Râsu", "Aegwynn", "mythic_plus_best_runs").SelectToken("mythic_plus_best_runs"));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static dynamic jsonRequest(String playerName, String realmName, String requestField)
        {
            String json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://raider.io/api/v1/characters/profile?region=eu&realm=" + realmName + "&name=" + playerName + "&fields=" + requestField);
            dynamic liste = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            return liste;
        }
```

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Net;
```

got used in this Project

I wanted to get the "dungeon" and the "key_level" string / int out of it for every single item, but when I did

```
Console.WriteLine(jsonRequest("Râsu", "Aegwynn", "mythic_plus_best_runs").SelectToken("mythic_plus_best_runs.dungeon"));
```

it just throws

```js
    {
        "name": "Râsu",
        "race": "Worgen",
        "class": "Druid",
        "active_spec_name": "Balance",
        "active_spec_role": "DPS",
        "gender": "male",
        "faction": "alliance",
        "achievement_points": 15570,
        "honorable_kills": 0,
        "thumbnail_url": "https://render-eu.worldofwarcraft.com/character/aegwynn/240/202932208-avatar.jpg?alt=wow/static/images/2d/avatar/22-0.jpg",
        "region": "eu",
        "realm": "Aegwynn",
        "last_crawled_at": "2022-03-22T08:24:35.000Z",
        "profile_url": "https://raider.io/characters/eu/aegwynn/Râsu",
        "profile_banner": "alliancebanner1",
        "mythic_plus_best_runs": [
          {
            "dungeon": "De Other Side",
            "short_name": "DOS",
            "mythic_level": 18,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-17T18:19:03.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 2274234,
            "par_time_ms": 2580999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 1,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 377,
            "zone_id": 13309,
            "score": 141.5,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Tyrannical",
                "description": "Bosses have 30% more health. Bosses and their minions inflict up to 15% increased damage.",
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=9"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Raging",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies enrage at 30% health remaining, dealing 50% increased damage until defeated.",
                "icon": "ability_warrior_focusedrage",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=6"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Volcanic",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically cause gouts of flame to erupt beneath the feet of distant players.",
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=3"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/2154109-18-de-other-side"
          },
          {
            "dungeon": "Spires of Ascension",
            "short_name": "SOA",
            "mythic_level": 18,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-19T19:23:45.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 2483104,
            "par_time_ms": 2340999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 0,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 381,
            "zone_id": 12837,
            "score": 134.2,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Tyrannical",
                "description": "Bosses have 30% more health. Bosses and their minions inflict up to 15% increased damage.",
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=9"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Raging",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies enrage at 30% health remaining, dealing 50% increased damage until defeated.",
                "icon": "ability_warrior_focusedrage",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=6"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Volcanic",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically cause gouts of flame to erupt beneath the feet of distant players.",
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=3"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/2540683-18-spires-of-ascension"
          },
          {
            "dungeon": "Plaguefall",
            "short_name": "PF",
            "mythic_level": 16,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-17T17:31:37.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 1641342,
            "par_time_ms": 2280999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 2,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 379,
            "zone_id": 13228,
            "score": 133.5,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Tyrannical",
                "description": "Bosses have 30% more health. Bosses and their minions inflict up to 15% increased damage.",
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=9"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Raging",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies enrage at 30% health remaining, dealing 50% increased damage until defeated.",
                "icon": "ability_warrior_focusedrage",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=6"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Volcanic",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically cause gouts of flame to erupt beneath the feet of distant players.",
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=3"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/2149124-16-plaguefall"
          },
          {
            "dungeon": "Theater of Pain",
            "short_name": "TOP",
            "mythic_level": 16,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-19T21:57:57.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 2127992,
            "par_time_ms": 2280999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 1,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 382,
            "zone_id": 12841,
            "score": 130.8,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Tyrannical",
                "description": "Bosses have 30% more health. Bosses and their minions inflict up to 15% increased damage.",
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=9"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Raging",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies enrage at 30% health remaining, dealing 50% increased damage until defeated.",
                "icon": "ability_warrior_focusedrage",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=6"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Volcanic",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically cause gouts of flame to erupt beneath the feet of distant players.",
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=3"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/2544779-16-theater-of-pain"
          },
          {
            "dungeon": "Halls of Atonement",
            "short_name": "HOA",
            "mythic_level": 15,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-19T20:28:03.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 1359135,
            "par_time_ms": 1920999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 2,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 378,
            "zone_id": 12831,
            "score": 128.7,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Tyrannical",
                "description": "Bosses have 30% more health. Bosses and their minions inflict up to 15% increased damage.",
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=9"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Raging",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies enrage at 30% health remaining, dealing 50% increased damage until defeated.",
                "icon": "ability_warrior_focusedrage",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=6"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Volcanic",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically cause gouts of flame to erupt beneath the feet of distant players.",
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=3"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/2544778-15-halls-of-atonement"
          },
          {
            "dungeon": "Sanguine Depths",
            "short_name": "SD",
            "mythic_level": 15,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-19T21:13:44.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 1827333,
            "par_time_ms": 2460999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 2,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 380,
            "zone_id": 12842,
            "score": 128.2,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Tyrannical",
                "description": "Bosses have 30% more health. Bosses and their minions inflict up to 15% increased damage.",
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=9"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Raging",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies enrage at 30% health remaining, dealing 50% increased damage until defeated.",
                "icon": "ability_warrior_focusedrage",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=6"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Volcanic",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically cause gouts of flame to erupt beneath the feet of distant players.",
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=3"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/2544767-15-sanguine-depths"
          },
          {
            "dungeon": "The Necrotic Wake",
            "short_name": "NW",
            "mythic_level": 15,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-17T16:31:27.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 1649375,
            "par_time_ms": 2160999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 2,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 376,
            "zone_id": 12916,
            "score": 128,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Tyrannical",
                "description": "Bosses have 30% more health. Bosses and their minions inflict up to 15% increased damage.",
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=9"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Raging",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies enrage at 30% health remaining, dealing 50% increased damage until defeated.",
                "icon": "ability_warrior_focusedrage",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=6"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Volcanic",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically cause gouts of flame to erupt beneath the feet of distant players.",
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=3"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/2142513-15-the-necrotic-wake"
          },
          {
            "dungeon": "Mists of Tirna Scithe",
            "short_name": "MISTS",
            "mythic_level": 17,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-09T15:25:20.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 2198966,
            "par_time_ms": 1800999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 0,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 375,
            "zone_id": 13334,
            "score": 127.2,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 10,
                "name": "Fortified",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies have 20% more health and inflict up to 30% increased damage.",
                "icon": "ability_toughness",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=10"
              },
              {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Bursting",
                "description": "When slain, non-boss enemies explode, causing all players to suffer damage over 4 sec. This effect stacks.",
                "icon": "ability_ironmaidens_whirlofblood",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=11"
              },
              {
                "id": 124,
                "name": "Storming",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically summon damaging whirlwinds.",
                "icon": "spell_nature_cyclone",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=124"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/956881-17-mists-of-tirna-scithe"
          },
          {
            "dungeon": "Tazavesh: So'leah's Gambit",
            "short_name": "GMBT",
            "mythic_level": 15,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-20T18:00:05.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 1529610,
            "par_time_ms": 1800999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 1,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 392,
            "zone_id": 1000001,
            "score": 126.9,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Tyrannical",
                "description": "Bosses have 30% more health. Bosses and their minions inflict up to 15% increased damage.",
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=9"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Raging",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies enrage at 30% health remaining, dealing 50% increased damage until defeated.",
                "icon": "ability_warrior_focusedrage",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=6"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Volcanic",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically cause gouts of flame to erupt beneath the feet of distant players.",
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=3"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/2626552-15-tazavesh-soleahs-gambit"
          },
          {
            "dungeon": "Tazavesh: Streets of Wonder",
            "short_name": "STRT",
            "mythic_level": 14,
            "completed_at": "2022-03-20T16:46:08.000Z",
            "clear_time_ms": 1887336,
            "par_time_ms": 2340999,
            "num_keystone_upgrades": 1,
            "map_challenge_mode_id": 391,
            "zone_id": 1000000,
            "score": 122.4,
            "affixes": [
              {
                "id": 9,
                "name": "Tyrannical",
                "description": "Bosses have 30% more health. Bosses and their minions inflict up to 15% increased damage.",
                "icon": "achievement_boss_archaedas",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=9"
              },
              {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Raging",
                "description": "Non-boss enemies enrage at 30% health remaining, dealing 50% increased damage until defeated.",
                "icon": "ability_warrior_focusedrage",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=6"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Volcanic",
                "description": "While in combat, enemies periodically cause gouts of flame to erupt beneath the feet of distant players.",
                "icon": "spell_shaman_lavasurge",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=3"
              },
              {
                "id": 130,
                "name": "Encrypted",
                "description": "Enemies throughout the dungeon possess relics of the First Ones. Destroy the relics to summon the First Ones' Automa and gain powerful bonuses, based on the order in which they were destroyed.",
                "icon": "spell_progenitor_orb",
                "wowhead_url": "https://wowhead.com/affix=130"
              }
            ],
            "url": "https://raider.io/mythic-plus-runs/season-sl-3/2650220-14-tazavesh-streets-of-wonder"
          }
        ]
      }
```

That's the Json File where i need the values from

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please attach the JSON as snippet in the question for better clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Saying "it just throws" (as you did) is like saying you asked your friend what he thought of something and you said he "replied".  Please _always_ include error messages in your questions.  Also, in general, you should always reconsider using `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the key "mythic_plus_best_runs" is an array.

So, you must loop over it to get all "dungeon" values.

```
var result = jsonRequest("Râsu", "Aegwynn", "mythic_plus_best_runs");

foreach (var item in result["mythic_plus_best_runs"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(item["dungeon"]);
}
```